# Authenticating inbound and outbound requests for an external service

Tags: managed-package, integration, oauth2, connected-apps

I am developing a service that uses a connected app to implement an OAuth flow for Salesforce users. I can store access and refresh tokens and use them to make requests into the orgs of the users who authorize the app.

But I also need users to be able to make requests to my service's API. The users will install a managed package which will have Apex that makes requests to my service. I'm not particularly concerned with the user making the request as much as which org the request is coming from and whether or not it's the org of one of the users who have already completed the aforementioned OAuth flow.

So my question is what is the best way to authenticate callouts to external services in a managed package in a way that conforms to Salesforce's security standards?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.